# confusion in numpy datatypes

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

the below program splits an rgb image into separate color channels

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
img = cv2.imread('dog_backpack.jpg')
cv2.imshow('RGB COLOR',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
B,G,R = cv2.split(img)
zero = np.zeros(img.shape[0:2],dtype="uint8")
cv2.imshow('RED',cv2.merge([zero,zero,R]))
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.imshow('GREEN',cv2.merge([zero,G,zero]))
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.imshow('BLUE',cv2.merge([B,zero,zero]))
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

on line 7 when i use np.zeros function with any int data type it throws an error but when i use it with uint8 it run properly.
please explain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `cv2.imread` will load the image using `np.uint8`, unless you change the flag.

You can also write like this:

```
np.zeros(img.shape[:2], dtype=img.dtype)
```

Comment: so it basically means they both need to be of same data type??

Comment: @YatinKumar yes